# extract specific xml child tags in xml file

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Im having xml file like

```
<LicenceQueryReply>
<LicenceQueryData>
    <LicInfo>
            <_fileId>EA100000.XML</_fileId>
            <_downloadTime>20110405003231+0000</_downloadTime>
            <_startTime>20080325000000+0000</_startTime>
            <_endTime/>
            <_capacity>0</_capacity>
    </LicInfo>
    <LicFeatureInfo>

            <_featureCode>307</_featureCode>
            <_featureName>HSDPA PFRP Scheduler</_featureName>
            <_capacityCode>unused</_capacityCode>
            <_maxCapacity>0</_maxCapacity>
            <_basicCapacity>0</_basicCapacity>
            <_usedCapacity>0</_usedCapacity>
            <_featureStatus>on</_featureStatus>
    </LicFeatureInfo>
```

from that xml file i just want to extract some specific tags like <_featurename>,, only...into other new xml file..

i would like to be done it with php or javascript

Comment: It would be better to tag your question with the programming language you are using.

Comment: added now....php or javascript would be prefered